# What is the actual purpose of boost::python::pure_virtual?

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

The documentation for `boost::python::pure_virtual` simply says:

> `pure_virtual` signals Boost.Python that the function f is a pure virtual function.

But I have no issue with the following code with or without `pure_virtual`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bpy = boost::python;

struct A {
  virtual std::string f() const = 0;  
  virtual ~A() { }
};

struct B: A {
  B() = default;
  std::string f() const override { return "B()"; }  
};

struct A_Wrapper: A, bpy::wrapper<A> {
  std::string f() const override { return get_override("f")(); }  
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    bpy::class_<A_Wrapper, boost::noncopyable>("A")
        .def("f", bpy::pure_virtual(&A::f))  // <-- Removing pure_virtual here changes nothing.
        .def("b", +[]() -> A* { return new B; }, bpy::return_value_policy<bpy::manage_new_object>()).staticmethod("b")
        .def("display", +[](A *a) {
            std::cout << a->f() << '\n';
        }).staticmethod("display")
        ;
}
```

And in python:

```
from example import A

b = A.b()
print(b.f())
A.display(b)

class A2(A):
  def f(self): return "A2()"

a2 = A2()
print(a2.f())
A.display(a2)
```

Outputs:

```
B()
B()
A2()
A2()
```

...as expected, with or without `bpy::pure_virtual`.

So, when should I use `pure_virtual`? What does it actually do?

Full working example on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33840d56f0fad9ea

Comment: There's definitely something wonky here. At the least, from what I can gather from the implementation, it should install a handler that throws a `RuntimeError` (with specific message) in situation where an override of the pure virtual is not provided... but so far I didn't manage to get that error either, just the same complaint in both cases about trying to invoke `NoneType`.

Comment: @DanMašek I actually also looked in the source and managed to get the `RuntimeError`. I think you get a `RuntimeError` if you try to call `a2.f()` from python if `A2` does not defined `f`, but you still get the same error about trying to invoke `NoneType` on the C++ side (you need to check the return value of `get_override` if you want a meaningful message). I asked this question because I thought this was doing something special but in the end it is just used to have a different message when calling from Python.